# Xpath found with Elements but not readable/scrapeable via rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape off the number amounts listed in a set of [donation websites](https://secure.actblue.com/donate/pete-buttigieg-announcement-day?refcode=website). So in this example, I would like to get

> $3, $10, $25, $100, $250, $1500, $2800

The xpath indicates that one of them should be

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/    
form/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/label
```

and the css selector

```
li.btn--wrapper:nth-child(2) > label:nth-child(1)
```

Up to the following, I see something in the `xml_nodeset`:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://secure.actblue.com/donate/pete-buttigieg-announcement-day"
read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(
  xpath = '//*[@id="cf-app-target"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div'
)
```

Then I see add the second part of the xpath and it shows up blank. Same with

```
X %>% html_nodes("li")
```

which gives a bunch of things, but all the `StyledButton__StyledAnchorButton-a7s38j-0 kEcVlT` turn blank.

I have worked with `rvest` for a fair bit now, but this one's baffling. And I am not quite sure how `RSelenium` will help here, although I have knowledge on how to use it for screenshots and clicks. If it helps, the website also refuses to be [captured in the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190428210117/https://secure.actblue.com/donate/pete-buttigieg-announcement-day?refcode=website)---there's only the background and nothing else.

I have even tried just taking a screenshot with `RSelenium` and attempting ocr with `tessaract` and `magick`,  but while other pages worked this particular example spectacularly fails, because the text is in white and in a rather nonstandard font. Yes, I've tried `image_negate` and `image_resize` to see if it helped, but it only showed that relying on OCR is rather a bad idea, as it depends on screenshot size.

Any advice on how to best extract what I want in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: it seems all values are in tags `label` and there are no other `label` so you could use only `//label` to get it - you don't need all of these `div` and `li`

Comment: I turned off JavaScript in web browser and checked page - it uses JavaScript to display it. But using DevTool in Chrome/Firefox I don't see taht it reads it from server. But in HTML I found this: `"amounts":[300,1000,2500,10000,25000,150000,280000]"` and it seems your values in cents.

Comment: @furas it was in *cents* (smacks forehead)---thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to extract numbers from script tag. You get a comma separated character vector

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
con <- url('https://secure.actblue.com/donate/pete-buttigieg-announcement-day?refcode=website', "rb")
page = read_html(con)
res <- page %>%
  html_nodes(xpath=".//script[contains(., 'preloadedState')]")%>%
  html_text() %>% as.character %>% 
  str_match_all(.,'(?<="amounts":\\[)(\\d+,?)+')
print(res[[1]][,1])
```

[image]

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/b4TMbw/1)